# How to recognize carriage returns with Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to read in a all the characters from a file, then convert them to morse code. This has been the simple part. However I do not know how to make the scanner recognize the carriage return then have the printwriter print out the carriage return.  Here is my code for converting the file:

```
public void encodeFile(String inputFilename, String outputFilename) throws Exception {

    // Scanner to read in and a printwriter to output what we encode
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFilename));
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFilename));

    //loop to run through the file and print out the encoded message
    while (in.hasNext()) {

        //temp string to hold the next word in the file
        String temp = null;
        temp = in.next();

        //loop to make the magic happen
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length(); i++) {
            char m; //temp char to hold the letter to encode
            m = temp.charAt(i); //gets the next char, sets temp equal to it
            output.print(toCode.get(m)); //prints the encoded string
            output.print(" ");
        }
        //prints a * in place of a space
        //output.print("*");
    }

    //closes the file; as is tradition
    output.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `in.hasNext()`, use `in.hasNextLine()` and initiate temp with `in.nextLine()` (now you know that temp is a line, and following it is carriage return)

Now, temp will be a string having multiple spaces, as I am guessing you will want to put a | between words (morse code). To do this, add space character to toCode() method returning "|" (or whatever you want to put between words)

In order to print carrage return you use

```
output.print("\n");
```

Comment: Also, if using `hasNextLine()`, `next()` should be appropriately changed to `nextLine()` as well.

Answer (score -1):

Carriage return is usually the '\n' character (on Unix like systems), or "\r\n" on Windows.

```
m = temp.charAt(i); //gets the next char, sets temp equal to it
if(m == '\n') {
    // Carriage return detected ...
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that the OP knows this, but is asking how to know when a carriage return has been scanned from the source file, so that s/he can place it in the output file appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for editing, but unfortunately, this will not work, because the carriage return is consumed as part of the delimiter of `hasNext()`.